# Access values from anypoint secrets manager in dataweave

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

Inside the secrets manager I have create a secrets group ("accessData") and stored an username / password as Shared Secret ("SAPcredentials") in this group.

In my mule flow I now would like to access these, but I haven't figured out how. I hoped for a method smiliar to the way parameters are handled in dataweave or global configurations, e.g.

```
p('accessData.SAPcredentials')
```

or

```
${accessData.SAPcredentials}
```

But apparently that's wrong - any suggestion how to do it right?

Comment: What is your deployment model? Deploying to Runtime Fabric, CloudHub, on prem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Anypoint Secrets Manager documentation](http://%20https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-security/index-secrets-manager) states that only can be used for some services:

> Secrets manager supports the management of TLS context for the following services:
>
> Runtime Fabric ingress
>
> You can store TLS artifacts in secrets manager and then configure Anypoint Runtime Fabric ingress with the secret reference.
>
> API Manager in CloudHub
>
> You can store the TLS artifacts in secrets manager and then configure Anypoint API Manager with the secret reference.

It doesn't look like it is possible to use it from a generic Mule application.

Comment: In that case, what would be the proper way to store credentials in Anypoint and access them in a Mulesoft app?